# Looking for assistance with batch file logic whether to determine whether a user has logged into AD or not

Tags: batch-file, active-directory

In attempting a proof of concept, we a script run by our desk for the creation of user home directories, group membership, profile, set home directory, etc.

I'd like to add a section that checks whether the account has the lastLogonTimeStamp (LLTS) value set in AD. I'm able query the user in AD. What I'm unable to figure out is how to parse out and run separate steps in the .cmd file whether there's a value in the LLTS attribute vs no value. I don't need to look at the age, just whether it's there or not.  I believe my issue is that I'm getting a string returned when I'm trying to compare a value, and if the LLTS isn't present, I'm not sure if it's a zero value or a null value.

I understand there may be better ways to do this using PS or VBS, but we're not at that point of converting our scripts, but we'd like to try an figure out this piece.

Here's what I have so far as a POC / test.

```
@echo off
:START
cls
echo Enter EMP ID
set /p EMPID=
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=0

:: queries for the existence of the lastLogonTimeStamp value 
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(samaccountname=%empid%))" -attr lastLogonTimeStamp') do (
set LLTS=%%a
set /a count=!count! + 1
if %%a GTR 1 GOTO COMPARE 
)

:COMPARE
echo.
echo OLD-LLTS=%LLTS%
set MODLLTS=%LLTS:  =%
echo MOD-LLTS=%MODLLTS%
IF %MODLLTS% GTR 1 GOTO HAS 

:HASNOT
:: Run these commands if the lastLogonTimeStamp is not present
ECHO Has NO previous Logon info.
pause
GOTO END

:HAS
:: Run these commands if the lastLogonTimeStamp is present, regardless of value.
ECHO Has previous Logon info.
w32tm.exe /ntte %MODLLTS%
pause
GOTO END

:END
EXIT
```

Here's example output with a user has previously logged in:

```
    administrator  
      lastLogonTimeStamp  
      131545455582093968
```

Here's example output with a user who's never logged in:

```
    guest
      lastLogonTimeStamp
```

**Note:There's an empty linebelow the attribute name for the guest that's not showing in the preview.**

Comment: If you show us some sample output from `dsquery`, showing the conditions you want to detect, no doubt we'd be better able to assist.

Comment: You could just use the `NET` command as well to get the last logon. `net user Squashman /domain`

Comment: Originally we build the POC using the NET user looking for the LastLogin value, however, this value is not replicated across the DCs and is only present on the DC the user authenticates against; we have nearly 100 DCs.  That's why we need to use the lastLoginTimeStamp, even though it's not up to the minute accurate, it's will have value if the user has logged.

Comment: @magoo I've tried to add an example of the ouput for the dsquery command, but where the timestamp value is present on the user with the value, there's a blank line for a user with no value set, this is translating in the preview.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q47309403.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q47309403_2.txt"

FOR %%a IN (logonname logonjunktext logontimestamp) DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "usebackqdelims= " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF DEFINED logonname (
  IF DEFINED logonjunktext (
   SET "logontimestamp=%%a"
  ) ELSE (
   SET "logonjunktext=%%a"
  )
 ) ELSE (
  SET "logonname=%%a"
 )
)

:done1
ECHO name=%logonname% junk text=%logonjunktext% timestamp=%logontimestamp%

FOR %%a IN (logonname logonjunktext logontimestamp) DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "usebackqdelims= " %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 IF DEFINED logonname (
  IF DEFINED logonjunktext (
   SET "logontimestamp=%%a"
  ) ELSE (
   SET "logonjunktext=%%a"
  )
 ) ELSE (
  SET "logonname=%%a"
 )
)

:done2
ECHO name=%logonname% junk text=%logonjunktext% timestamp=%logontimestamp%


GOTO :EOF
```

I used files named `q47309403.txt`, `q47309403_2.txt` containing your data for my testing. Obviously, replace such with your `dsquery` command.

The code is simply the same, repeated for each file for demo purposes.

The data reported in the variables should enable you to derive any consequential actions, if your report on the `dsquery` output is representative.

Operation is simply clear three variables, then accumulate each depending on the `defined` state for the variable.

Comment: Thanks, however,  it's not obvious to me how I'd apply your contribution to my POC script.  The output sample provided is representative if I strip everything away and just run the dsquery command by itself from a command prompt, obviously,  substituting the %empid% variable with an actual domain account sam account. I just can't figure out how to take what you added and apply that.

Comment: You would need to  replace `"%filename?%"` in the `for` with the quoted `dsquery` command from your original post, which is unlikely to run on my machine. You would also need to remove the `usebackq` from the `for` options (it's just there for processing a quoted filename). The results appearing in the three variables should then be the 2/3 lines that `dsquery` produces, according to your example. Process those lines as you wish.

Comment: I tried this and not doing what I'm expecting. What I'm looking to accomplish, is the ability to have the batch execute the :HAS section, if there's an attribute value returned, indicating that the user HAS logged on previously, or run the :HASNOT section if the attribute value is blank, which would indicate the user has never logged on to the domain previously.

Comment: You are using the term "attribute value" which I do not understand. Given that you have two situations where one produces three lines of output, then all three variables will contain values. If it produces only two non-empty lines, then the `logontimestamp` variable will be empty. You can differentiate between the two situations using `if defined logontimestamp goto has) else (goto hasnot)` When you arrive at those labels, `logontimestamp` will contain the timestamp found (if it is found) and `logonname` the account found in the data returned by `dsquery`